# Javascript parse URL detect length

Tags: javascript

I use this function to parse url parameters

```
function parseURL(url) {
    var a =  document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    return {
        source: url,
        protocol: a.protocol.replace(':',''),
        host: a.hostname,
        port: a.port,
        query: a.search,
        params: (function(){
            var ret = {},
            seg = a.search.replace(/^\?/,'').split('&'),
            len = seg.length, i = 0, s;
            for (;i<len;i++) {
                if (!seg[i]) { continue; }
                s = seg[i].split('=');
                ret[s[0]] = s[1];
            }
            return ret;
        })(),
        file: (a.pathname.match(/\/([^\/?#]+)$/i) || [,''])[1],
        hash: a.hash.replace('#',''),
        path: a.pathname.replace(/^([^\/])/,'/$1'),
        relative: (a.href.match(/tps?:\/\/[^\/]+(.+)/) || [,''])[1],
        segments: a.pathname.replace(/^\//,'').split('/')
    };
}
```

I can call this function by:

```
var currentURL = parseURL(window.location.href);
console.log(currentURL.params['price']);
```

But I'm trying to figure out the length of params..to verify if has any parameter already.

```
console.log(currentURL.params.length) // doesn't work -> returns undefined
```

Now you ask me: why do you want to know the length? Because I have another function:

```
function filter(type, currentURL){
    var result = "";
    var url    = document.location.href;

    if(currentURL.params[type] != undefined){
        var price   = currentURL.params[type];

        if(url.indexOf('&' + type + '=asc') > 0){
            result = url.replace("&" + type + "=asc", "&" + type + "=desc");
        }else if(url.indexOf("?" + type + "=asc") > 0){
            result = url.replace("?" + type + "=asc", "?" + type + "=desc");
        }else if(url.indexOf("&" + type + "=desc") > 0){
            result = url.replace("&" + type + "=desc", "&" + type + "=asc");
        }else if(url.indexOf("?" + type + "=desc") > 0){
            result = url.replace("?" + type + "=desc", "?" + type + "=asc");
        }
    }else{
        result = url + "&" + type + "=asc";
        if(currentURL.length == 0){
            // The problem is here
            result = url + "?" + type + "=asc";
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Because if I have no parameters, I should put: `index.php?price=asc` and NOT `index.php&price=asc`.

**Edit: Solved** with @Pointy help.

```
result = url + "&" + type + "=asc";
if(window.location.search.length == 0){
   result = url + "?" + type + "=asc";
}
```

Comment: What would you expect to happen for `some/url?length=42`?

Comment: The `window.location` object already separates out the different parts of the URL. `window.location.search` is everything after the `?` for example. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location)

Comment: @SLaks yes. If I have no parameters in the URL I expect to redirect to `?price=asc`, otherwise, if I have already parameters in the URL, I should redirect to: `parameters&price=asc`

Answer (score 1):

Only arrays and strings have a `length`, unless you explicitly make one.
Instead, you can call `Object.keys(x).length`.

Comment: That's not strictly true, Strings have length too: var myString = 'Hello there!'; `myString.length` is 12.